# loading images in canvas facing the lag and is slow. How can I enhance its smoothness in Angular

Tags: angular

"I want to render the images smoothly, resembling video streaming. Can anyone help me check my code below?

Currently, I am using the worker service to offload image processing, and the main thread is only responsible for sending the images. However, when playing a YouTube video, there is lag and slowness."

`````
    if (typeof Worker !== "undefined") {
      this.renderingWorker = new Worker(
        new URL("../worker.worker.ts", import.meta.url)
      );
      this.renderingWorker.onmessage = (event: any) => {
        if (event.data.error) {
          console.error(event.data.error);
          this.rendering = false;
          return;
        }

        const processedFrames = event.data.processedFrames;
        // for (const processedFrame of processedFrames) {
        this.updatedCanvas(processedFrames);
        // }
      };
    } else {
      console.log("Web Workers are not supported");
    }
  }

  private initSocketListener() {
    this.sessionSocket.SocketMessagesImage.subscribe((message) => {
      this.frameEmitted(message);
    });
  }

  private frameEmitted(frameData: any): void {
    // Add the new frame to the buffer
    this.buffer.push(frameData);

    if (!this.rendering) {
      // Start rendering process if it's not already in progress
      console.log("Rendering started");
      this.renderImages();
    } else {
      console.log("Frames skipped, rendering in progress");
    }
  }

  private renderImages(): void {
    // If there are frames in the buffer, proceed with rendering
    if (this.buffer.length > 0) {
      // Send buffer data to the rendering Web Worker
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        console.log("Sending frames to worker");
        this.renderingWorker.postMessage({ buffer: this.buffer });

        // Clear the buffer after sending it to the worker
        this.buffer = [];

        // Continue rendering frames
        this.rendering = false;

        // Check if there are more frames in the buffer to render
        if (this.buffer.length > 0) {
          // Call renderImages recursively to process the next set of frames
          console.log("More frames in buffer, rendering next set");
          this.renderImages();
        }
      });

      this.rendering = true;
    } else {
      console.log("No frames in the buffer, rendering complete");
    }
  }
  private updatedCanvas(processedFrames: string[]): void {
    const context = this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");

    // Update canvas size if needed
    const resChanged =
      this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.height !== this.imageToDraw.height;
    this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.height = this.imageToDraw.height;
    this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.width = this.imageToDraw.width;

    // Handle aspect ratio changes
    if (resChanged) {
      this.handleAspectRatioChange();
    }

    // Clear canvas only once before drawing the frames
    context.clearRect(
      0,
      0,
      this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.width,
      this.mobileCanvas.nativeElement.height
    );

    const drawFrame = (frame: string) => {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + frame;

      // Handle image load errors
      image.onerror = (_event) => {
        console.error("Error loading image");
      };

      image.onload = (_event) => {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        // Apply any additional logic (e.g., scaling) here
        if (this.WindowResized) {
          this.scaleScreen();
        }
        this.imageToDraw = image;

        // Check if there are more frames to draw
        if (processedFrames.length > 1) {
          // Draw the next frame after a short delay (e.g., 16ms for 60fps)
          setTimeout(() => {
            drawFrame(processedFrames.shift()!);
          }, 10);
        } else {
          // All frames have been drawn
          this.rendering = false;
        }
      };
    };

    // Start drawing frames
    if (processedFrames.length > 0) {
      drawFrame(processedFrames.shift()!);
    }
  }

addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  const buffer = event.data.buffer;
  const processedFrames = [];

  for (const frameData of buffer) {
    // Process the frame asynchronously
    // ...

    const processedFrame = frameData;
    processedFrames.push(processedFrame);
  }

  // Send the processed frames back to the main thread
  postMessage({ processedFrames });
});````
`````

Comment: you shouldn't use setTimeout there... instead use requestAnimationFrame: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame  You should probably also avoid base64.